# OnEdit Google Scripts in same sheet - Separately they work, together not so well

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have these scripts working separately but when I combine them or create two different scripts only one will function.
What am I missing?

```
function onEdit(e) {

var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(),

    editCols = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]

if (sheet.getName() !== 'THANG11' || editCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==

    -1 || e.range.rowStart < 3 || e.range.rowStart > 6) 

if (sheet.getName() !== 'THANG12' || editCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==

    -1 || e.range.rowStart < 3 || e.range.rowStart > 6)   

    return;

sheet.getRange("I1").setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: you have an compile error on assignment of sheet variable, remove the , at the end

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus How to fix it ? Do you know? Thanks.

Comment: I can see only one script in your question. Can you show what your separate working scripts look like?

Comment: @CocoNess Sheet name "THANG11" ok => "THANG12" not work. And contrary.

Comment: @ziganotschka
Apple sheet name "THANG11"

function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    editCols = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
if (sheet.getName() !== 'THANG11' || editCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==
    -1 || e.range.rowStart < 3 || e.range.rowStart > 6) return;
sheet.getRange("I1").setValue(new Date());
}

Comment: @ziganotschka
Apply sheet name "THANG12"

function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    editCols = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
if (sheet.getName() !== 'THANG12' || editCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==
    -1 || e.range.rowStart < 3 || e.range.rowStart > 6) return;
sheet.getRange("I1").setValue(new Date());
}
```
THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

### There are two possibilities to merge your if statements.

> First possibility

```
function onEdit(e) {
  ...
  if (sheet.getName() != 'THANG11' || ...){
    return;
    } 
  if (sheet.getName() != 'THANG12' || ...){  
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange("I1").setValue(new Date());
  ...
}
```

In this case you implement two separate `if` statements and specify within curly brackets the block of code to execute if the respective condition is fulfilled.

In your case, the code to execute is identical for both coditions (`return`), thus you can implement both conditions within one `if` statement:

> Second possibility

```
function onEdit(e) {
  ...
  if (sheet.getName() != 'THANG11' || sheet.getName() != 'THANG12' ||...){
    return;
    }
  sheet.getRange("I1").setValue(new Date());
  ...
}
```